# Cartesian to Polar Coordinates Confusion

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

[image]
Here $R$ is the unit circle. My question is in the second step can we substitute 1 for $x^2+y^2$ instead of $r^2$. In this case the answer will be $3\pi$. Which is correct $3\pi$ or ${3\pi}/2$?

Comment: Unit circle or unit disk?

Comment: Unit circle. It’s to find work done by a force field on a particle moving on an unit circle once in counterclockwise direction.

Comment: It is very clear (from the $\iint$ and the $dA$) that the integrals on the first line are integrated over a region, not along a curve. This may be an application of a form of Stokes' Theorem. It is possible to get the value of an integral around the boundary of a region by doing a different integral inside the region. The fact that you want the end result to be work done around a circle does not dictate what kind of integral you must use.

Comment: In any case the equations you have shown are undoubtedly correct. What you have not shown is how your source material (where you got these equations) connected the first integral to the work done on the particle, or any other information that would enable someone to deduce the correct answer to the "work done" question. Obviously there are some steps missing on the left side of the first $=$ sign, and there was probably some text that would explain things.

Answer (score 1):

You are integrating the area inside the unit circle, so the unit disk.

$$x² + y² = r² \neq 1$$

$$ 0 \leq x² + y² \leq 1$$

The answer is $3 \pi /2$.

Comment: It’s about finding the work done by a force field in moving a particle along an unit circle using Green’s theorem.

Comment: @danny The integral presented in the first step is a double integral. So either you misunderstood the integral, or the book is wrong (which I doubt it is)